# declared name in.h but reports undeclare in .cpp in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

Below is my code:

MathCore.h

```
#ifndef __CC_MATHCORE_H__
#define __CC_MATHCORE_H__

#include "math.h"
class MathCore
{
public:
    MathCore();
    virtual ~MathCore( );
    int x (int n  );
};

#endif
```

MathCore.cpp

```
#ifndef __CC_MATHCORE_H__
#define __CC_MATHCORE_H__

#include "MathCore.h"

MathCore::MathCore()//a
{

}
MathCore::~ MathCore()//b
{

}
int MathCore::x (int n  )//c
{
    float v=0;
    return v;
}
#endif
```

but it erports error at

```
a:C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
  Use of undeclared identifier 'MathCore'
b:Expected a class or namespace
c:Expected a class or namespace
```

Your comment welcome

Comment: Take your preprocessor definitions out of the C++ file!

Comment: Double underscore uppercase identifiers and defines are reserved for the compiler. You should change it to something like `CC_MATHCORE_H` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have that `#define` in both the .cpp and .h files, as it will prevent the contents of the .h file from actually being included.

When you `#include` a file, for all practical purposes it behaves the same way as copying and pasting that file into wherever you have the `#include`. So, the first few lines of your MathCore.cpp are effectively this:

```
#ifndef __CC_MATHCORE_H__
#define __CC_MATHCORE_H__

#ifndef __CC_MATHCORE_H__
#define __CC_MATHCORE_H__
/* the rest of your .h file here */
```

When restructured that way, it becomes a little more obvious, that second `#ifndef` can never match since the symbol it's checking is defined immediately above.

Answer (score 3):

Because, in your C++ file, you're using the same header guards as your header. The second line defines `__CC_MATHCORE_H__`. After this, you include the header, which does *nothing* if `__CC_MATHCORE_H__` is defined. Remove the guard from the cpp file, and you'll be fine. Guards are rarely, if ever, needed in actual implementation files.

Answer (score 1):

```
//////////////////////////////////MathCore.cpp 
#include "MathCore.h"

MathCore::MathCore()//a
{

}
MathCore::~ MathCore()//b
{

}
int MathCore::x (int n  )//c
{
    float v=0;
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the include guard from MathCore.cpp